# In REST, create a single content type or have seperate content types for each resource representation?

Tags: rest

If I want to follow the practice of using a custom content type for my REST API, am I supposed to define a single custom content type for my entire project or define custom content types for each resource representation (what is sent to/back from my REST API) used on my project?

That is, if I am building a "Bookstore" REST API where the services say are in the namespace com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp, do I create a single content type:

```
Content-Type: application/com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp+xml
```

Or do I create a content type for each type of data that can be posted/retreived via my Bookstore REST APIs?

```
Content-Type: application/com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp.user+xml
Content-Type: application/com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp.order+xml
Content-Type: application/com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp.book+xml
```

Comment: From what I have researched, I am seeing that folks _are_ creating specific mime types to represent the data passed to a REST API. In my case, we are NOT doing HATEOAS. We are building an enterprise application that is effectively doing POX over HTTP (and calling it "REST"). We would like to leverage the capability to define the version of content type in order to allow for versioning when we have different parts of our enterprise app being built at different times.

Comment: So if projects A and B use a service built by project C and A and B are on different release cycles such that A must use version 1.0 an B must use verison 2.0 of the "book" content type when it calls the same URI, then we want to leverage the ability to use the "Accept" header e.g. "Accept: Content-Type: application/com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp.book-v1+xml" and "Accept: Content-Type: application/com.mycompany.mybookstoreapp.book-v2+xml" for a GET request. Hopefully this provides more context and this  will start to receive some answers... people seem to keep voting it up as a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describing a content type for each data seems the safest solution. If you want to be HATEOAS compliant later for some reasons, it will be easier. In another hand, it doesn't make much sense to have one content type for everything. The content **type** describes the type for a specific data.

About versioning, you can add versioning to your API in three different ways. First, you can add the version number in your URIs, this is the easy way:

```
/api/v1/users
```

Or you can use your new content type:

```
application/vnd.acme.user-v1+xml
```

Or you can also use a qualifier in your Accept header, that way you don’t touch your content type:

```
application/vnd.acme.user+xml;v=1
```

It’s really up to you. The first solution is easy but less RESTful than the two other solutions. But those solutions require more smart clients.