# Custom content type - is registering with IANA mandatory?

Tags: rest, mime-types, custom-type

I'm developing an API as RESTful as possible (though the HATEOAS constraint is not met thus it is **not** a REST API *per se*)

I'm versioning the API, and since there are several ways to do this, I think I'm going to use the Accept header. I do know the alternatives, but the purpose of this question is not to find a suitable way to version the API.

As far as I know, there are two ways to version API using the Accept header, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750376), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037587) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974295/1988372):

```
application/vnd.company.myapp-v1+json
```

or using a qualifier

```
application/vnd.company.myapp+json;v=1
```

While this is quite clear, I understood that all `x-` custom content types have been [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) and `vnd.` content types have to be registered with IANA.

The API is not and will not be public, all the clients using it are developed internally.

Is registering a custom vnd. content type with IANA mandatory? What happens if the content type is not registered?
Can I simply use Accept header `application/vnd.company.myapp+json;v=2` even without registering it with IANA?

Since I need a custom content type for content negociation purely for versioning purposes, can I use qualifier such as `application/json;v=2` ?

Answer (score 8):

From what I can read from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.2 it is not mandatory, however if you have and API that is public it is encouraged to do so.

RFC6838 is about registering new MIME/Media Types, with the following text it doesn't seem to be a problem for private API (product)

> The vendor tree is used for media types associated with publicly
> available products.

Also it is not required for the public API (product), like I said it is encouraged.

> While public exposure and review of media types to be registered in
> the vendor tree are not required, using the media-types@iana.org
> mailing list for review is encouraged, to improve the quality of
> those specifications.  Registrations in the vendor tree may be
> submitted directly to the IANA, where they will undergo Expert Review
> [RFC5226] prior to approval