# Register own media type with IANA if the consumer of REST API is internal

Tags: rest, mime, restful-architecture, media-type, iana

I'm developing an API as RESTfull as possible and I need to create my own custome media types application/vnd[...]+json.

Do i need to register with IANA  if API is being consumed by specific team? Same question is being asked already but there is no answer to it. [Is registering with IANA mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121241/custom-content-type-is-registering-with-iana-mandatory)

Answer (score 1):

No. Vendor-specific MIME types don't need to be registered with IANA. That process if for MIME types that you think are general enough to be widely useful across platforms, vendors, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Now i understand why we need IANA.