# MIME type for a drl file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, drools

I need to provide download option for a drl file. So what ***MIME type*** should I give to download **.drl file**. I could not find a type for .drl. Please help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A DRL file is simply a text file](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e2785). Just use `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

I checked the list of [standard MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), which includes registered vendor and personal MIME types. None of them seem to be drools-related.

Of course, you can always use `text/plain` as a fallback, but then your browser/client will treat the .drl files exactly like text files and, for example, display them, instead of, say, passing them to drools automatically.

Therefore, it might make sense to use something like `text/prs.drl`. I believe you are allowed to do this [without registering the MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452951/2421916), although it is discouraged.

Registering a vendor type such as `text/vnd.drl` would probably be best and [can be done by third parties](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.2) (you or me!) without taking "ownership" away from RedHat. This would probably be the best path forward. I don't dare to start this undertaking today, but since I am facing the same problem, this is something I am looking at.